# Find the "average" discrete distribution for some summary statistics?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, average, descriptive-statistics

The new law requires companies to make summary statistics of salaries publicly available:

1. Mean
2. Standard deviation
3. First quartile
4. Median
5. Third quartile

For $n$ people working at a company the true values of wages is a list of $n$ elements that has exactly this summary statistics. However, the number of possible lists is obviously finite!

Let's take this finite number of lists and order their elements. It is now possible to calculate the average of each $k$-th ($1 \le k \le n$) element. I think the list of average elements would be a very reasonable reconstruction of possible wages (I called it an "average" discrete distribution in the title).

How should I approach this problem? Could you suggest some references?
Also, maybe there are more ways to reconstruct the sensible values easily?

---

Edit: after more than a year, I'm still thinking about this problem.

Comment: Look for write-ups on "Bootstrapping".

Comment: @MaggieMyers As I understood, bootstrapping is all about taking random samples from the dataset. And I don't have a dataset...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the first read.  It seems that you actually have in general  N company lists of size $n_i$ , i=1,..N, and want to look at the averages of order statistics to reconstruct the distribution of wages.  I thought you wanted to construct from lists (data), the distribution of the summary statistics, which could be done through bootstrapping.  I don't know how to direct you since, especially since $n_i$ aren't necessarily the same.  if k=1, this is the minimum but k-1000 may be median or max or not even exist for a particular list.  But then, I again may be misunderstanding.

Comment: Look here maybe: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/estimating-a-distribution-based-on-three-percentiles

Comment: Why are the number of lists "obviously finite"? Are the wages assumed to be non-negative integers?

Comment: @mhum - that's what I assumed in my contemplations. You fan assume differently if that makes anything easier.

Comment: I see no reason to believe that all of the possible distributions (that satisfy these constraints) are equally likely, so taking a mean over all the possible distributions is probably not very informative.  In the real world, incomes tend to follow certain trends that would not be captured here.  But it is an interesting problem, and solving this case could open up the discussion to more general cases.  I am curious whether the result will have an obvious connection to the central limit theorem or to some kind of maximum entropy principle.

Comment: An easy place to start would be finding the maximum-entropy distribution that satisfies the constraints and see if it agrees with numerical results for some small $n$, say, $n=10$.  It is likely that, given that the constraints involve quantiles, the maximum-entropy distribution would have to be found numerically as well.

Answer (score 2):

I see two disadvantages with the proposed approach: First, I don't know how to calculate a representative distribution without first enumerating all possible distributions which fit the summary statistics, and, though finite under an integer assumption, there are likely prohibitively many distributions that will satisfy the statistics. Second, even if every individual distribution satisfies the summary stat criteria, there is no guarantee that the "average" of these distributions as you describe it will still satisfy the mean and standard deviation criteria.

However you go about constructing a distribution, the fact is that there are only five numbers given, and so any full distribution will have to fill in the huge information gap with some assumptions. The classical statistical way to do this is through fitting a parametric distribution to the data on hand, where the shape of the distribution fills in the gaps nicely. I think that approach would work well here, though maybe not as exciting and nonparametric as your idea. Given that this is an income distribution, I'd suggest looking at power law distributions or some other right-skewed, heavy-tailed distribution.

Depending on your application, there is another way of looking at the problem, called distributionally robust optimization (DRO). DRO is based on other optimization theory such as linear and robust optimization, and identifies decisions which work well *no matter which* distribution is the correct one, given the summary statistic information.

Comment: Although you did not offer a specific way to generate any viable solution, the provided thoughts are very valuable. So much so that I'm giving you the reward. I am in progress of fitting data to a Pareto distribution and then doing some adjustments to optimise for all summary statistics. Will provide an update when it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the given summary statistics are $m,s,q_1,q_2,q_3$.

One approach is to create a distribution in which

- 26% of the values are $q_1$
- 26% of the values are $q_2$
- 26% of the values are $q_3$
- 11% of the values are $x$
- 11% of the values are $y$

Any such distribution will have the right median and quartiles, so we can solve for $x$ and $y$ to get the right mean and standard deviation.

This can lead to negative or complex solutions for $x$ and $y$ which are not reasonable salaries, but in many cases this simple procedure will produce a reasonable distribution of salaries with the desired properties.

**Example:** The American Medical Informatics Association reported just this data on a recent salary [survey](https://amia.org/sites/default/files/AMIA-2018-Salary-Survey-20181031.pdf): "The overall mean (standard deviation) salary of the biomedical informatics respondents in this study was \$181,774 (\$99,566) and the median (interquartile range) was \$165,000 (\$111,000-\$230,000)."

Solving for $x$ and $y$ shows that this is consistent with a distribution where

- 11% of the values are \$44,125
- 26% of the values are \$111,000
- 26% of the values are \$165,000
- 26% of the values are \$230,000
- 11% of the values are \$412,366

Comment: Looks like a clever trick. I really appreciate that this answer provides a very specific recipe to produce a possible solution!